# Background-color with fixed height disturbs my document flow

Tags: html, css, height, background-color

I need my bg color to be fixed size and I want my `#second-div` to start after `<hr>`. 
But this fixed height of bg-color messes up my doc flow and `h1`-s of the `bg-div` appear over my `#second-div`. 
Any thoughts how can I fix it?

I've tried using `clearfix` but it does no help, as `bg-div` has no floats...

EDIT: to specify - I need those h1-s to overflow the green bg. 
WORKAROUND: I've created another div just for fixed-height-bg and then gave `bg-div` a negative top margin. Visually it satisfies my needs, but wanted to know, if there is a simpler solution.

```
<head>
  <style>
    .bg-div { 
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #00FF00; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bg-div">
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="second-div">
    <h1>second div content</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

[codepen link with same html-css to play around](https://codepen.io/Hinnun-gagap/pen/qBOpEEL)

Comment: You need to increase the size of the `bg-div`, as the `h1` elements are _overflowing_ out of it because there combined height is more than what you have set for the `bg-div`. But the `#second-div` will start from the 200px only as you have fixed `bg-div`'s height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a fixed background color as part of the layout, I'd try an absolutely positioned `div` just for that purpose. See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/wvKpaEQ) for reference

```html
<div class="bg-block"></div>
<div class="first-div">
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <h1>bg-div-content</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
<div id="second-div">
  <h1>second div content</h1>
</div>
```

```css
.bg-block { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#00FF00;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

NOTE:
1. using multiple `h1`s is usually discouraged, as `h1` implies the top hierarchy of the content
2. using an absolute size unit for this type of layout concept is typically less flexible, so I'd suggest you consider other design approach if possible.

Comment: thanks. 
also, I'm aware about h1-s, just used them for purpose of example

Answer (score 0):

if you keep height fixed then the content is obviously going to overflow. That's not good practice do `height:100%` and see that it fits really well and is dynamic based on the content. Your html should be dynamic because you cannot expect the size of the content in real time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the height you're setting for `bg-div` is just too small to fit all the `H1` elements you're putting inside it.  You can make the `H1` elements smaller by setting their `font-size` to something smaller.  Alternatively, if you don't care about losing some of the content that you put inside `bg-div`, you can set `overflow: hidden` on `bg-div`.  This will prevent the browser from displaying any content from `bg-div` that would otherwise be outside the bounding rectangle of the div.

Comment: situation is - i need those h1-s to overflow the bg, but not the upcoming div.